# android Using binarySearch to get the index to be added to List

Tags: android, arraylist, z-index, binary-search

Hi I have and android app that contruct list of object (topStories). When a new item `TopStory` is added to the list (`topstories`) (the list is initial an empty `ArrayList`). I want to determine the `index` that the new item should be add so that the List `topstories` remain in order of specific variable (TopStory.time). How to use `binarySearch` to determine the index. Anyhelp is much appriciate. Thanks

Here is my model class

```
public class TopStory {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int score;
    private JSONArray kids;
    private long time;
    private String url;

    public TopStory() {
    }

    public TopStory(int id, String title, String author, int point, long time,String url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.score = point;
        this.time = time;
        this.url = url;
    }
```

I have used these code but have error

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(topStories,topStory, new Comparator<TopStory>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(TopStory lhs, TopStory rhs) {
                                return (int) (rhs.getTime()-lhs.getTime());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean equals(Object object) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
topStories.add(index, topStory);
```

the error is

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index -1, size is 0
                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:147)
                                                                       at com.vic.hackernew.ItemListActivity$5.onResponse(ItemListActivity.java:199)
                                                                       at com.vic.hackernew.ItemListActivity$5.onResponse(ItemListActivity.java:182)
```

Comment: why dont you read the documentation of `Collections#binarySearch` and `List#add` methods?

Comment: hi sorry. just figure out it should be topstories.add(-index-1,TopStory) just simple but did not notice. Thanks alot

Comment: not always: if `binarySearch` returns >= 0 just use that index, it is in case if you are adding the duplicates

Comment: so perfect one we should like if (index < 0) index = -index -1; then topstories.add(index,TopStory). can cover duplicate?

Comment: yes or with one-liner `topstories.add(index < 0? -index  - 1 : index, topStory)`

Comment: thanks a lot. I ve learn much about BinarySearch. Very good for recycleView

Comment: btw instead of providing the external `Comparator` your class can implement `java.lang.Comparable` and you just call `binarySearch(topstories, topStory)`

Comment: thanks, should we use Comparable or Comparator? I found Comparator easier to implement

Comment: `Comparator` has two methods to implement, `Comparable` has one

Comment: Hi successful implement interface but can we have another one that sort by for example TopStory.score?

Comment: ok so indeed `Comparator` is better in that case, since you can pass two different `Comparator`s